# Force RPi3B Ethernet to connect gigabit

Tags: networking, ethernet, ethernet-port

My RPi3B and my PC are connected to gigabit Cisco switch. My PC's Ethernet gets connected 1000 Mbps but RPi3B's Ethernet connects 100 Mbps. Does anyone know what settings should I perform to get gigabit Ethernet on RPi3B?

P.S. I tested the cables many times with other devices and they are fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cheapest way to get gigabit ethernet on the Pi Zero?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93477/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-get-gigabit-ethernet-on-the-pi-zero)

Comment: There is no magical command to transform a 100Mbps controller into a 1Gbps one.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I thought it's gigabit Bront

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B does NOT support gigabit ethernet. Only Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ does.

Comment: O jesus! my whole life was a lie. You have no idea how much time I spend on this. Thanks

Comment: Even the Pi3B+ will only achieve about 220Mbps due to the usb limit https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-gigabit-networking

Comment: no I was wondering why it doesn't connect as gigabit and always connects as 100mbps. now I know why.